# Creating instance of class having $inject

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have created a class to open a modal dialog.

```
export class ModalDialog {
  private open: boolean;
  private modalInstanse: angular.ui.bootstrap.IModalServiceInstance;

  constructor(
    @Inject('$uibModal')
    private $uibModal: angular.ui.bootstrap.IModalService
  ) {
    this.open = false;
  }

  public isOpen(): boolean {
    return this.open;
  }

  public closeDialog(): void {
    this.modalInstanse.close();
  }

  public dismissDialog(): void {
    this.modalInstanse.dismiss();
  }


  public openDialog( templateUrl: string, controller:any  ): void {
    this.modalInstanse = this.$uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: templateUrl,
      controller: controller
    });
    this.open = true;
    this.modalInstanse.result.finally((): void => {
      this.open = false;
    });
  }
}
```

Now how can I use this class.

I was expecting we can use it as

```
ModalDialog md = new ModalDialg();
md.openDialog(someTemplate,someController);
```

I am doing something wrong here. Can someone explain? Sorry if this seems like stupid question.

- Do I need to pass $uibModal as parameter to ModalDialog() ?
- Since $uibModal is injected what is the best way to create ModalDialog?

Comment: You call `Open` when your method name is `OpenDialog`, for a start.

Comment: What is the error? What is not working? Log messages? How can we help if we don't know what is wrong?

Comment: Error will appear at ModalDialog md = new ModalDialg();